# ValueError: port should be of type int

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have been trying to connect my FastAPI server and MySQL Database using Docker-compose.
However, it keeps showing the error (`ValueError: port should be of type int`) when I run `docker-compose up  --build`.

I have attached a full log of the error. It seems that the error is coming from `connectionstring` of MySQL (I am attaching my `db.config` file)

Could you please help me, with what changes I need to make in order to run MySQL and FastAPI server using docker-compose?

The following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql-db:
    container_name: mysql-db
    image: mysql:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE='admin'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='admin'
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  backend-server:
    container_name: "backend-server"
    build: .    
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
```

My database configuration file is following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

DB_USER = "root"
DB_PASSWORD = "admin"
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = 3306
DATABASE = "admin"


connect_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?port={}?charset=utf8'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DATABASE, DB_PORT)


engine = create_engine(connect_string)
meta = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
```

My docker file for FastAPI Server

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR '/backend' 
COPY ./requirements.txt  ./
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
COPY .  .   
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app"]
```

The error log on terminal is as follow:

```
Creating mysql-db ... done
Creating backend-server ... done
Attaching to mysql-db, backend-server
mysql-db          | 2022-03-23 02:25:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
backend-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
backend-server    |     sys.exit(main())
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
backend-server    |     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
backend-server    |     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
backend-server    |     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
backend-server    |     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 437, in main
backend-server    |     run(app, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 463, in run
backend-server    |     server.run()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
backend-server    |     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
backend-server    |     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
backend-server    |     return future.result()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
backend-server    |     config.load()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 458, in load
backend-server    |     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
backend-server    |     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
backend-server    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./main.py", line 4, in <module>
backend-server    |     from routes.planner import planner
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./routes/planner.py", line 2, in <module>
backend-server    |     from config.db import conn
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./config/db.py", line 16, in <module>
backend-server    |     conn = engine.connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3210, in connect
backend-server    |     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
backend-server    |     else engine.raw_connection()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3289, in raw_connection
backend-server    |     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3256, in _wrap_pool_connect
backend-server    |     return fn()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
backend-server    |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
backend-server    |     rec = pool._do_get()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
backend-server    |     self._dec_overflow()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
backend-server    |     return self._create_connection()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
backend-server    |     self.__connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
backend-server    |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
backend-server    |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
backend-server    |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
backend-server    |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 290, in __init__
backend-server    |     raise ValueError("port should be of type int")
backend-server    | ValueError: port should be of type int
mysql-db          | 2022-03-23 02:25:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
backend-server exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy (now at least) expects the port after the hostname:

```
connect_string = f'mysql+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_DATABASE}?charset=utf8'
```

This uses an f-string instead to make it a bit more readable and less prone to errors (since usage of `{}` and `.format` requires you to keep track of the sequence). This only works on Python 3.6+, so if you're on an older version, rewrite it to use the old format syntax.

I also recommend using `utf8mb4` as the charset to avoid issues with extended utf8 characters (such as emojis, etc.), and apply a collation as well (if necessary):

```
?charset=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_<language>_ci
```

Comment: As far as I know, (also stated in documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) `port` is not after the host in `PyMySQL` client for SQLAlchemy.

Comment: That seems correct, yeah. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/pymysql.py - there is no kw force type for the port parameter, so it might jus tnot be properly supported with pymysql. However, since OP uses 3306 - leaving it out might be the best solution for now. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py#L232

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @stuck and @MatsLindh! I have tried the options you have suggestions, but no luck :D